# error in Configure Tomcat 7 realm

Tags: tomcat, web.xml, configure, jdbcrealm, context.xml

Hi can anyone help me with it , I spend whole evening but couldnt make it work :(
here is in my web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
          <web-resource-name>Welcome</web-resource-name>
          <description>Accersible by authorized user only</description>
          <url-pattern>/Welcome.jsp</url-pattern>
          <http-method>GET</http-method>
          <http-method>POST</http-method>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint>
          <role-name>member</role-name>
          <role-name>manager</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
      <user-data-constraint>
          <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
      </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>


   <login-config>
      <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
      <form-login-config>
          <form-login-page>/Login.jsp</form-login-page>
          <form-error-page>/wrongUser.jsp</form-error-page>
      </form-login-config>    
  </login-config>
```

When I enter a worng username or password it will lead to the wrongUser.jsp(it must connect to the database), but if I enter the correct username and password, it shows:
message Invalid direct reference to form login page
description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Invalid direct reference to form login page).

Anyone has an idé what is wrong with it? Thanks in advance

Comment: have you configured realm in your server.xml ?

Comment: yes, and it looks like it is connect to the database. it shows the errorpage if the username or password not suit